# Setup HTTPS as default but allow HTTP?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I've an nginx vhost setup with both HTTP and HTTPS.

I'd like to make visitors which write in the address bar "www.example.com" to be directed to the HTTPS version of my website, but if they specify `http://www.example.com` then I'd like them to get the HTTP version.

I have tried setting the ssl `listen` as `default_server` but nothing seems different...

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    listen *:443 ssl spdy default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/custom/www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/custom/www.example.com.key;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
}
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

If the user specifies 'www.example.com' the browser simply assumes `http://www.example.com`. While you can redirect the http:// then to https:// there is no way to do this only if the access was caused by the browsers assumption, that is you cannot distinguish between the user entering http://... and the browser assuming http://...